# Select Max date column in a sql query, which is joined to other columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle Query below

```
    select papf.person_number, to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Resignation Date", paam.last_update_date as assignmentupdate, hrcd.last_update_date as hrcdupdate, hth.last_update_date as hthupdate

from 
per_all_people_f papf, per_all_assignments_m paam, hrc_txn_header hth, HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd
where 
papf.person_id=paam.person_id
and paam.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
and paam.assignment_status_type in ('ACTIVE')
and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
and paam.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE ='Y'


and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam.effective_start_date) and trunc(paam.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(papf.effective_start_date) and trunc(papf.effective_end_date)

and paam.person_id=hth.subject_id(+) 
and paam.assignment_id=hth.object_id(+)
and hth.module_identifier(+) IN ('Resignation','Terminations')
and hrcd.transaction_id(+)=hth.transaction_id

and papf.person_number IN ('901626', '900723', '900846');
```

Which is giving below result

[image]

Now I am Person 900846 has multiple rows coming, now I need to extract the max date from this column for that I added the below logic but this is not working

```
    select papf.person_number, to_char(hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY','NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Resignation Date", paam.last_update_date as assignmentupdate, hrcd.last_update_date as hrcdupdate, hth.last_update_date as hthupdate

from 
per_all_people_f papf, per_all_assignments_m paam, hrc_txn_header hth, HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd
where 
papf.person_id=paam.person_id
and paam.assignment_type IN ('E','C')
and paam.assignment_status_type in ('ACTIVE')
and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
and paam.EFFECTIVE_LATEST_CHANGE ='Y'


and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam.effective_start_date) and trunc(paam.effective_end_date)
and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(papf.effective_start_date) and trunc(papf.effective_end_date)

and paam.person_id=hth.subject_id(+) 
and paam.assignment_id=hth.object_id(+)
and hth.module_identifier(+) IN ('Resignation','Terminations')
and hrcd.transaction_id(+)=hth.transaction_id

and hrcd.SUBMITTED_DATE = 
(SELECT MAX(hrcd2.SUBMITTED_DATE)
    FROM HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd2, hrc_txn_header hth2, per_all_assignments_m paam2
    WHERE hrcd2.TRANSACTION_ID = hrcd.TRANSACTION_ID
    AND hrcd2.transaction_id=hth2.transaction_id
    and hth2.module_identifier IN ('Resignation','Terminations')
    and paam2.assignment_id=hth2.object_id
    and paam2.assignment_id=paam.assignment_id
    )

and papf.person_number IN ('901626', '900723', '900846');
```

But now the Output is like below

[image]

I am not sure how the outer join will be added in the second query and even after after that the result should 3 lines of data each for employee with max resignation date and blank is resignation date is null

Output should look like below
[image]

can someone help me in this?

Thanks,
Shivam

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: You should prefer modern ANSI join syntax rather then old Oracle join syntax. Try to reduce your query and remove unrelated stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions (`ROW_NUMBER | RANK | DENSE_RANK | MAX` `OVER`) to rank your rows and only pick the latest per person. E.g.:

```
select person_number, "Resignation Date", assignmentupdate, hrcdupdate, hthupdate
from
(
  select
    papf.person_number,
    to_char(hrcd.submitted_date, 'DD-Mon-YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') as "Resignation Date",
    paam.last_update_date as assignmentupdate,
    hrcd.last_update_date as hrcdupdate,
    hth.last_update_date as hthupdate,
    hrcd.submitted_date,
    max(hrcd.submitted_date) over (partition by papf.person_number) as max_submitted_date
  from per_all_people_f papf
  join per_all_assignments_m paam on paam.person_id = papf.person_id
  left join hrc_txn_header hth on hth.subject_id = paam.person_id
                              and hth.object_id = paam.assignment_id
                              and hth.module_identifier IN ('Resignation', 'Terminations')
  left join  HRC_TXN_DATA hrcd on hrcd.transaction_id = hth.transaction_id
  where papf.person_number IN (901626, 900723, 900846)
  and paam.assignment_type IN ('E', 'C')
  and paam.assignment_status_type in ('ACTIVE')
  and paam.primary_flag = 'Y'
  and paam.effective_latest_change = 'Y'
  and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(paam.effective_start_date) and trunc(paam.effective_end_date)
  and trunc(sysdate) between trunc(papf.effective_start_date) and trunc(papf.effective_end_date)
)
where (submitted_date = max_submitted_date)
   or (submitted_date is null and max_submitted_date is null)
order by person_number;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer but looks like there is no table for hrcd2 alias ? How this table should be joined

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was a typo. The alias is `hrcd` of course. If corrected the error.